# Twilio Device status is always returning an offline value

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, twilio

I'm trying to use the Twilio Client on an AngularJS app. Server side is on Laravel PHP. I tested the Quickstart for PHP and I'm trying to adapt it to this actual case.

I created an endpoint on Laravel to get a capability token on angular -I'm  getting it already- then:

```
vm.token = response.token;
vm.message = response.identity;

Twilio.Device.setup(vm.token);

Twilio.Device.ready(function(device){
   vm.message = "Twilio.Device ready";
});
```

Since nothing happened, I placed a button to verify the status of Twilio.Device

```
function deviceStatus(){
   vm.status = Twilio.Device.status();
}
```

The status is always returning OFFLINE. I already verified account id, token and Twiml app sid and everything is ok.

Am I doing something wrong? missing some step?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here. Is this in development and on localhost? Can you try in debug mode (`Twilio.Device.setup(vm.token, { debug: true })`) and see what it says?

Comment: @philnash Localhost. Where should I see debug messages or?

Comment: If you setup debug mode like above, you should see debug messages in your browser's devtools console.

Answer (score 0):

Browser only allows media control when your site or domain has SSL, which access media controls like audio or video io

If insecure the connection will be terminated.